# Detecting if a code is running with or without debugging in VSCode keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, key-bindings

In VSCode, in keybindings.json file, how can I detect if a code runs with or without debugging (f5 or ctrl+f5) Especially when the code is waiting for an input in which both states are 'inDebugMode' && debugState == 'running'

```
// Restart the 'Run without debugging' process
{
    "key": "some keybinding",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.restart",
    "when": "inDebugMode && debugState == '???'"
},

// Restart the 'Debugging' process
{
    "key": "some other keybinding",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.restart",
    "when": "inDebugMode && debugState == '???'"
}
```

In the above code sample, I intend to assign a keybinding to restart the "Run without debugging" process (ctrl+f5), and another to restart the "Debuging" process (f5)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: if you use the same command to restart why does it matter

Comment: Forget about the 'restart' command. Assume I want to run different commands in different situations!

Comment: what specifically about `inDebugMode` is insufficient here?

Comment: No, it cannot differentiate between the "run without debugging" and "debugging" modes. For example when the code is waiting for an input, both are "inDebugMode" and "debugState == 'running'"